# React-Native: how to detect assistive technology and user preferences

Tags: android, accessibility, react-native, uiaccessibility, android-a11y

We need to detect if a person is using VoiceOver, Switch Control, TalkBack, or Switch Access to display alternate buttons on our swipe-dependent application. 
Normally we'd look for `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning`, `AccessibilityManager`, and other hooks to detect the need to display these buttons.

We are also respecting the user's preference for bold fonts and simplified animation via hooks like `UIAccessibilityIsBoldTextEnabled()`.

I couldn't find documentation within React that details how we can get this type of information from the device and write the logic for changing the app's interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a web developer, so this may or may not be relevant:  Could you not default to the non-VoiceOver view, but if a single item on the page becomes focused or scrolled *without at least one `ontouchdown` event*, then you now know that non-touch input is being used, and then enable the alternative behavior?